# Atribuição de valores a um array numerico de valores um query em PHP

Tags: php, array, query

Dada a tabela `marcas` da base de dados `teste_db` (por exemplo)

```
| id |  marca  |

| 1  | mercedes|
| 2  |   audi  |
| 3  |   fiat  |
| 4  |   alfa  |
| ...|   ...   |
|573 | ferrari |
|574 | bentley |
```

e dado um array com `n` argumentos numéricos como por exemplo:

`$arr = array('3','23','127','574')`

e partindo do princípio que o array vai sempre conter argumentos numéricos que podem ser encontrados na coluna `id` da referida tabela, gostaria de incluir no array, a cada argumento deste, o valor `marca` cujo `id` na tabela tem o mesmo valor do array, e o resultado seria:

```
$arr = array("3"=>"fiat", "23"=>"rover", "127"=>"tata", "574"=>"bentley");
```

Qual seria o código necessário para esta tarefa? PHP e mysqli.

Comment: E o que exatamente seria `$k` e `$v`? Pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar como ficaria o resultado desejado?

Comment: O `$k`e o `$v` são as chaves e valores, respectivamente de um array onde `array ( $k => $v)`

Comment: De qual *array*? Está confuso. Qual a relação do *array* `$arr` e a tabela do banco de dados? O que exatamente você quer fazer? Lembre-se de adicionar à pergunta o exemplo do resultado esperado.

Comment: Se o procedimento é feito, com eu imagino, usando `mysqli_query`, está obviamente implícita a ligação à base de dados. A minha questão será após este passo.

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi bem, você pode fazer algo como:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query('SELECT marca FROM marcas'))
{
    $arr = array('1', '2', '3', '4');
    $bancoDeDados = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
    $resultado = array_map(null, $arr, $bancoDeDados);

    print_r($resultado);
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/M8jC0d) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/MeanStupendousStud)</sup>

Que o resultado seria algo semelhante a:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => mercedes
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => audi
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => fiat
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => alfa
        )

)
```

Com a função `array_map`, passando o primeiro parâmetro como `null`, será retornado um par com os respectivos valores de `$arr` e `$bancoDeDados`.

Comment: O resultado pretendido é esse mas eu quero fazer coincidir os valores do array com os da tabela que podem nao ser ordemados ou seguidos.

Comment: @Goncalorsr entende agora o porque eu pedi a relação do *array* com o banco de dados? Isso não estava claro na pergunta.

Comment: @Goncalorsr editei a ersposta. Veja se é isso, pois se não for, tem mais coisas que não estão claras na pergunta.

Comment: Se calhar podia ter especificado mais... culpa minha. A tabela que dei como exemplo é, na realidade, uma tabela com 573 entradas. Vindo de outra parte do código, que não é relevante, obtenho um array que pode ter 1 ou 2 ou 3 ou 30 ou 50 valores entre 1 e 573 (ex: array(2, 5, 24, 36, 345)). Agora queria associar a cada valor do array o valor "marca" cujo id na tabela tem o mesmo valor do array, e resultar em array('2' =>'Nissan', '5' =>'Ferrari', '24' => 'Bentley' ... e por aí fora.

Comment: @Goncalorsr então a pergunta está longe de perguntar isso. Por favor, edite a pergunta e detalhe o que comentou. Somente depois disso eu editarei a resposta com a solução.